# consume gsoap webservice from .NET client

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services, gsoap

From a .NET application, how do I consume a Web Service developed using gSoap c/C++ library?

I can create a C/C++ client using gSoap library to consume the web service. But I need to consume it from within a .NET (C#) application. I tried Adding a Web Reference but that doesn't seem to work.

Would I need to work with raw Soap Packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Web reference was not working was the hand crafted WSDL. It worked fine with gSoap library and gSoap C/C++ code generrator nut not with VS. With some changes in the way WSDL was written, I am now able to consume the gSoap C/C++ web service by adding a Web Reference in Visual Studio and also by using HTTP GET method.

Steps taken -

- Instead of adding Web reference, use wsdl.exe in verbose mode to generate code using thee gSoap WSDL and XSD file
- change the WSDL file to resolve any error and warnings reported by wsdl.exe
- Once wsdl.exe can successfully generate code using the WSDL, you can now use VS add web / service reference wizard

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call the Web Service dinamically (without adding the reference)

- [Call a webservice dynamically without webreference](http://blog.codergenie.com/post/Call-a-webservice-dynamically-without-webreference.aspx)
- [Building Dynamic SOAP Requests with ASP.NET C#](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20011103.asp)

You can also try to build a WCF client, and generate the managed source code file for a proxy using the [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).

- [How to: Create a Windows Communication Foundation Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx)

Finally, the [ProxyFactory](http://proxyfactory.codeplex.com/) project lets you build the proxy classes without WCF

Comment: Thank you but I have resolved the Web reference error in other way. Upvoted your answer for alternate approaches.